# partial match dictionary key(of tuples) in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary that maps 3tuple to 3tuple where key-tuples have some element in common

```
dict= { (a,b,c):(1,2,3),
        (a,b,d):tuple1,
        (a,e,b):tuple,
        .
        (f,g,h):tuple3,
        .
        .
        .
        tuple:tuple
      }
```

now how can I find the values that match to (a,b,**anyX**) in a dictionary `ie (1:2:3) and tuple1`

this is computer generated and very large thus, it takes effort to determine anyX.

so, any good ways I can do this?

edit:partial matching of (f,g,*),(f, *,g) to tuple3 will also be helpful but not necessary.

Comment: do you also need to support get(f,*,h) returning tuple3?

Comment: not in the current version, but that would also be great

Comment: Notes: `(1:2:3)` causes a `SyntaxError`, and it's generally not a good idea to name variables after builtins, such as `tuple` and `dict`.

Comment: sorry I meant (1,2,3) and dict and tuple was to show the idea

Comment: Note that stating and solving this problem leads to a situation when you no longer take advantage of the hash structure underlying the dictionary, i.e. you iterate over all elements to find the matching tuple, instead of taking using the tree that organizes the dictionary. Thus the access is probably much slower.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lets say if you're passing `None` for the missing keys then you can use `all` and `zip`:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> import random
#create a sample dict
>>> dic = {k:random.randint(1, 1000) for k in permutations('abcde', 3)}
def partial_match(key, d):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if all(k1 == k2 or k2 is None  for k1, k2 in zip(k, key)):
            yield v
...         
>>> list(partial_match(('a', 'b', None), dic))
[541, 470, 734]
>>> list(partial_match(('a', None, 'b'), dic))
[460, 966, 45]
#Answer check
>>> [dic[('a', 'b', x)] for x in 'cde']
[541, 734, 470]
>>> [dic[('a', x, 'b')] for x in 'cde']
[966, 460, 45]
```

Comment: if all(k1 == k2 or k2 is None  for k1, k2 in zip(k, key)): yield v "wow this is some mind bending line"

Comment: @TheAvs `all()` will return True if all items satisfied the condition `k1 == k2 or k2 is None`, and `zip()` returns items on the same index from both iterables. `yield` is used to make a generator function.

Comment: In Python 3.x , .iteritems() is replaced with .items()

Comment: I am getting an error. I think the code doesn't works if we try to find a tuple `(1,2,None)` instead of `( 'a' , 'b ' , None )` .The error is `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 4):

You could reconstruct your dictionary into a triply nested dict.

```
dict= { ("foo", 4 , "q"): 9,
        ("foo", 4 , "r"): 8,
        ("foo", 8 , "s"): 7,
        ("bar", 15, "t"): 6,
        ("bar", 16, "u"): 5,
        ("baz", 23, "v"): 4
      }

d = {}
for (a,b,c), value in dict.iteritems():
    if a not in d:
        d[a] = {}
    if b not in d[a]:
        d[a][b] = {}
    d[a][b][c] = value
```

Here, `d` is equivalent to:

```
d = {
    "foo": {
        4:{
            "q": 9,
            "r": 8
        },
        8:{
            "s": 7
        }
    },
    "bar":{
        15:{
            "t": 6
        }
        16:{
            "u": 5
        }
    },
    "baz":{
        23{
            "v": 4
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can easily iterate through the possible third keys, given the first and second.

```
#find all keys whose first two elements are "foo" and 4
a = "foo"
b = 4
for c in d[a][b].iterkeys():
    print c
```

Result:

```
q
r
```

This only works for matching the third key. For instance, you wouldn't be able to find all second keys, given the third and the first.

Comment: This is the only one so far with sublinear lookup times. +1 and this data structure can be used to look in any position, with an accessor function.

Answer (score 1):

There might be other ways, but assuming you just need to do a single search (in other words there might be ways to build better data structures for repeated searching):
(Note that this handles arbitrary lengthed tuple's with the '*' in multiple possible locations)

```
def match(tup,target):
   if len(tup) != len(target):
      return False
   for i in xrange(len(tup)):
      if target[i] != "*" and tup[i] != target[i]:
         return False
   return True

def get_tuples(mydict,target):
   keys = filter(lambda x: match(x,target),mydict.keys())
   return [mydict[key] for key in keys]

#example:
dict= { (1,3,5):(1,2,3),
        (1,3,6):(1,5,7),
        (1,2,5):(1,4,5),
       }
print get_tuples(dict,(1,3,'*'))
```

.

Comment: This correctly answers the question, but with O(n). The point of a dict is to get O(1) lookup. Just a heads up the wildcard search will be slow compared to a lookup. If convenient for the rest of your code use a better data structure for wildcard search.

Comment: I have timed your function and it performs constantly slower than the implementation by @hcwhsa by about 0.012 seconds for a dictionary of about 10,000 elements. And thank you very much for quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

[@AshwiniChaudhary's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18894071/9209546) can be trivially adapted for an object-oriented solution. You can subclass `dict` and add a method:

```
class tup_dict(dict):
    def getitems_fromtup(self, key):
        for k, v in self.items():
            if all(k1 == k2 or k2 is None for k1, k2 in zip(k, key)):
                yield v

d = tup_dict({("foo", 4 , "q"): 9,
              ("foo", 4 , "r"): 8,
              ("foo", 8 , "s"): 7,
              ("bar", 15, "t"): 6,
              ("bar", 16, "u"): 5,
              ("baz", 23, "v"): 4})

res = list(d.getitems_fromtup(("foo", 4, None)))  # [9, 8]
```

Comment: I have to say that although this solution looks promising, it is extremely slow for large dictionaries.

Comment: @Corel, Agree. Though, to note, it should be no faster or slower than a one-off generator (as per Ashwini's solution) that doesn't use subclassing. For performance, you would need to consider a specialist data type which supports efficient lookup of this kind.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about other ways to do it? I am trying to use a dictionary to store edge information in a graph implementation, but as I said, when the dictionary becomes big (even on a graph with 200 nodes) it becomes impractical to try to do the partial matching this way.

Comment: @Corel, If you are able to convert all your data to numeric, then you can use a NumPy array which has memory optimisation benefits.