# If in python dictionary, multiple keys are assign to a value then how to get value by using one of the key?

Tags: python

d = dict({('a','b'):1})
then how to get value by using either d.get('a') or d.get('b') instead of d.get(('a','b'))

```
>>> d=dict({('a','b'):1})
>>> d.get('a')  // should return value as 1
>>> d.get('b')  // should return value as 1
>>> d.get(('a','b'))
1
>>>
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't work like that. Could you just store the same value under each key separately?

Comment: You'd have to create your own data type to do something like that.  A dictionary simply gives you back the value associated with the key you  used when storing the value.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a partial match function similar to, but simpler than, the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893624/partial-match-dictionary-keyof-tuples-in-python).

```
def partial_match(d, part_key):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if part_key in key:
            return value

>>> partial_match(d, 'a')
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dedicated data structure derived from `dict`:

```
>>> class MyDict(dict):
...     def __init__(self, *args):
...         if args and type(args[0]) is dict:
...             for k, v in args[0].iteritems():
...                 self.__setitem__(k, v)
...         dict.__init__(self, *args)
...     def __setitem__(self, keys, val):
...         dict.__setitem__(self, keys, val)
...         if type(keys) is tuple:
...             for k in keys:
...                 self.__setitem__(k, val)
... 
>>> d=MyDict({('a','b'):1})
>>> print d.get('a')
1
>>> print d.get('b')
1
>>> print d.get(('a','b'))
1
>>>
```

This creates new entries in the dictionary as suggested by @Thrustmaster.

The alternative is to create a 'partial match' function as @Stuart has proposed, that uses less memory as entries are not duplicated, but using more computations as it requires looping through all keys, effectively making the key hashes useless.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, dictionary is simply a key-value mapping. You give it a single key, it will return a uniquely identifiable value against it.

To be able to get the value from the `dict` using any of the elements in the tuple, then you'd need to use something like the below:

```
>>> def updateDict(d, obj):
...     for key, value in obj.items():
...         for k in key:
...             d[k] = value
... 
>>> res = {}
>>> updateDict(res, {('a','b'):1})
>>> res
{'a': 1, 'b': 1}
>>> res['a']
1
>>> res['b']
1
```

Note that the code above merely inserts the values multiple time one for each element in the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the dictionary you want using the original dict:

```
d1 = dict({('a','b'):1})

# creates {'a':1, 'b':1 }
d2 = {x:v for k, v in d1.items() for x in k}

print d2.get('a')  # prints 1
print d2.get('b')  # prints 1
```