# Fast datastructure for doing geohash lookups

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

I have two sets of data, A and B, that I am trying to create matches between.  Values in set A correspond to locations of people, and values in set B correspond to locations of cities.  Location here is represented by a 10-digit geohash string.

I want to make a fast loop that, for every person in set A, associates a city from set B.  I found this fairly easy to do by having A and B as lists and using for loops.  However, the O(n) efficiency of the for loops is undesirable.  My second attempt at this problem was to use dictionaries to get O(1) time.  I want to do something like this:

```
for z in A.keys():
    for x in range(0,10):
        try:
            match_list.append([z,B[z[:-x]])  --this partial string lookup is not supported with dictionaries.
        except blahblahblah:
        .....
```

For those without geohash background: truncating a geohash string is like "zooming out" or trimming the decimals off a lat,long pair.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893624/partial-match-dictionary-keyof-tuples-in-python) stackoverflow post for implementations that involve itertools, but I am too inexperienced to make sense of how to use them in this context.

Also, I have thought about making multiple dictionaries for each hash lengther, but this is problematic because there is a large up-front computational cost for making these dictionaries.

If anybody has a way to implement my idea, or an idea for a fast datastructure that could acheive my goals, please let me know!    Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could try some sort of gridded data structure, with say 5x5 deg buckets for each cell. Then put the cities in their corresponding bucket. Once you have that the search space is probably a lot smaller. I dunno, I'm just spitballing here...

Comment: If you don't care about memory too much you can just store each city multiple times for each fragment of the geohash. The accepted answer in your linked post has linear lookup time btw. [Edit: I just read that that you already thought about that, so just ignore me :)]

Comment: You could try using a tree. Each node on level 'i' represents the 'i'th character of your hash. Inserting would be traversing the tree and storing the city at each node you pass. Finding a prefix would be traversing the tree until you reach your limit or have no match, and then just returning the current set of cities. That would also give you the closest matching location. Not sure if that is any faster than using multiple dicts though.

Comment: How would you handle the case where more than one city has the same geocode prefix.  That is, what if `B[z[:-x]]` returns more than one city? Or no city?  It would also help to post the code you are using now (the list and for-loop version that works slowly).

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody.  I ended up using the method suggested by Shore - a "Trie" datastructure.

RootTwoMar:  In the end, if more than one city is returned, then I do a "brute force" calculation of distance on the sphere (earth).  This would be computationally expensive if I had to do it with ALL cities, but it ends up being quite fast because usually just 3 or 4 are returned.