# Using Python 'not in' on dict with tuple key where I don't have all tuple parts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a script that reads a list of `users` and `reports` from a MySQL database and runs a function for each of the values. The script checks the db every 5 minutes and adds these value pairs to a dictionary. As I loop through I don't want to re-add value pairs that are still in the dictionary. I've had no issues handling that with this code:

```
if (user, report) not in t1.reports_to_call:
    t1.add(report, user)
```

My issue is that I want to also check a dictionary `t2.reports_requested` where the key is a tuple of three parts `user`, `report` and `some_unknown_id`. If there a way to run `not in` on a dictionary where you only know 2 of three elements and want to wildcard the third?

I have been also looking to see if I can refactor this secondary dictionary and move `some_unknown_id` out of the key as I do think it may be the case that the user/report pair is unique in this dictionary. But if I determine I need to wildcard the third value what is best way to do this?

```
{('user', 'report', 'some_unknown_id'): {}}
```

Comment: Nope. Linear search is the best you can do. The key is hashed and must be exact, so I'd pursue the user/report pair as key if that's the unique part and you can always provide both, or use a nested dict keyed by `user` with sub-dicts for the other properties you may need to key on.

Comment: Sounds fair.  I think I can refactor the second dict if necessary, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing an easy answer

Comment: There is no way to do this directly. If you need the `t2.reports_requested` dictionary to have three keys, one way is to use a nested dictionary, where the first dictionary uses the two keys and points to a second dictionary that indexes based on the third key (you can use `defaultdict` to make the first dictionary simpler to use).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [partial match dictionary key(of tuples) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893624/partial-match-dictionary-keyof-tuples-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set` and check if a new pair it is a subset of the `t2.reports_requested.keys()`

```
values_exist = [True for k in reports_requested.keys() if set(["user","report"]).issubset(k)]
if not values_exist:
    print("Add new tuple")
    pass
```

For example:

```
reports_requested = {('user', 'report', 'some_unknown_id'): {}, ('user1', 'report', 'some_unknown_id'): {}, ('user1', 'report', 'some_unknown_id2'): {}}
new_pair = {'user1', 'report2'}

values_exist = [True for k in reports_requested.keys() if new_pair.issubset(k)]
if not values_exist:
#     print("Add new tuple")
    pass
```

Performance check with timeit: `1.06 µs ± 184 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot check for the existence of keys in a dict using wild-cards.

Make a dict of dicts:

```py
{('user', 'report'): {
    'some_unknown_id': {},
}
```

or even better:

```py
{'user': {
    'report': {
        'some_unknown_id' : {},
    },
}
```

Then you have the best of all worlds.

You can first check whether a user occurs, and if so, whether in combination with a report, and if so, whether in combination with some other identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to extract "sub-keys" for testing against, as

```
if (user,report) not in zip(*list(zip(*t2.keys()))[0:2]):
  #etc
```

Here, the `[0:2]` extracts only the first two components of the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can't wildcard the key but you could replace the third key with None if it isn't there:

```
x = {('user','report'): {'dummy': 1}, ('user','report', 'unknown_key'): {'dummy': 2}, }

new_dict = dict(zip({(k[0], k[1], k[2] if len(k) == 3 else None) for k in x.keys()}, x.values()))

new_dict

{('user', 'report', 'unknown_key'): {'dummy': 1},
 ('user', 'report', None): {'dummy': 2}}
```

This way you'll always know the length of the key and you can test the last value.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the default `get` operation of the dictionary and add such element if `None` is returned as follow.

```py
if not t1.get((user, report), default=None):
    t1.add(report, user)
```

for the `t2`, I'd suggest to do a two level dictionary, sort of:

```py
t2 = {
    ('user', 'report'): {
        'some_unknown_id': {},
        'some_unknown_id_2': {},
    }
}
```

In that fashion you can handle several "third unkown keys" right under `('user', 'report')`.